# Having a problem to parse Yaml file with python

Tags: python, yaml

I have the below section in YML file and I'm trying to read the IP address and hostname of the servers in order to verify that I don't have duplication (can see each IP once and each hostname)

I'm failing at the first stage while trying to ready the IP address. WIll be happy to get help with both reading and verify there is no duplication

Thank you

```
import yaml


with open(r'.\environment.yml') as file:
    environment = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
print(environment ['server_details']['ip'])
```

YML File

```
server_details:
 - {ip: "{{ yum_repository.ip }}" , hostname: "{{ yum_repository.hostname }}"}
 - {ip: "{{ cloudera_managment_server.ip }}" , hostname: "{{ cloudera_managment_server.hostname }}"}
 - {ip: "{{ postgres_server.ip }}" , hostname: "{{ postgres_server.hostname }}"}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.30 , hostname: master1}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.31 , hostname: master2}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.32 , hostname: master3}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.36 , hostname: worker1}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.37 , hostname: worker2}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.38 , hostname: worker3}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.39 , hostname: kafka1}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.40 , hostname: kafka2}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.41 , hostname: kafka3}
 - {ip: 10.201.51.44 , hostname: gw1}
```

Comment: What is the failure?

Comment: `environment['server_details']` appears to be a list. You have to index into it first.

Comment: @BoseongChoi This is the error  C:\DevOps\Big_Data\Cloudera-api\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/DevOps/Big_Data/Cloudera-api/check-values.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/DevOps/Big_Data/Cloudera-api/check-values.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(cloudera_environment ['server_details']['ip'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @AdamSmith 

And how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As @AdamSmith mentioned, you should traverse(or index) list first.

```py
import yaml


with open(r'.\environment.yml') as file:
    environment = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
for server_detail in environment['server_details']:
    print(server_detail['ip'])
```

You can make it list, too

```py
ip_list = [server_detail['ip'] for server_detail in environment['server_details']]
```